# Setting a custom view based on folder contents

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, document-library, custom-field-types, sharepoint-views, custom-view

We are in the process of rebuilding our entire SharePoint site, using yes/no fields and custom views are going through each document library and setting a yes/no value on each document depending on if they are still active. We then have a second view to show only those documents that have a yes value.

This works great until a folder is involved, so my question:

Is is there a way we can create a view based on the contents of a folder, something like `if folder contains active document`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SharePoint View are not able to only show folders contain "active" document. Here are workarounds you can try:

1. If you create a new view and select in the filter section.

   > Content Type Equals Folder
   >
   > OR
   >
   > And then add the additional condition you wish to apply to the
   >   documents.

In this way all the folders will be displayed no matter it contains active document or not.

2. Edit the view to show all items without the folders
   [image]
   You can find all required documents while the folder hierarchy will be lost.

Comment: thanks very much Jerry, should have noticed the folder options in view! This will get us what we need